# Sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'd like to sort by time,day.
Here is my attempt:

```
var days = new Array();
var days['SU'] = 0;
var days['MO'] = 1;
var days['TU'] = 2;
var days['WE'] = 3;
var days['TH'] = 4;
var days['FR'] = 5;
var days['SA'] = 6;

events.sort(function(a, b)
{
    if(a['day'] != b['day'])
    {
        return (days[a['day']] < days[b['day']]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    else if(a['time'] != b['time'])
    {
        return (a['time'] < a['time']) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
);
```

It's not tested, but am I doing it correct?
(Time asc, days asc) Mon 8am, Tues 8am, Mon 9pm is the order I'm looking for.

Cheers.

```
events[0]['day'] = 'MO';
events[0]['time'] = 8;
events[1]['day'] = 'MO';
events[1]['time'] = 21;
events[2]['day'] = 'TU';
events[2]['time'] = 8;
```

My solution which seems to work thanks to @T.J. Crowder

```
events = new Array();
events[0] = new Array();
events[0]['day'] = 'MO';
events[0]['time'] = 8;
events[1] = new Array();
events[1]['day'] = 'MO';
events[1]['time'] = 21;
events[2] = new Array();
events[2]['day'] = 'TU';
events[2]['time'] = 8;

var days = {
    'SU': 0,
    'MO': 1,
    'TU': 2,
    'WE': 3,
    'TH': 4,
    'FR': 5,
    'SA': 6
};

events.sort(function(a, b)
{
    if (a.time != b.time)
    {
        return a.time - b.time;
    }
    else if (a.day != b.day)
    {
        return days[a.day] - days[b.day];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Condensed:

```
events.sort(function(a, b)
{
    return a.time != b.time
       ? a.time - b.time
       : days[a.day] - days[b.day];
});
```

Comment: Try posting the data you are sorting, the attempt at sorting and the sorting result. From  your post I gather you wrote some code and came here asking us if it arbitrarily works.

Comment: To add to @Khez: why not simply test it, and then ask here if you actually have a problem?

Comment: Well first and foremost, you should be using an Object and not an Array - JavaScript arrays are not associated arrays, while objects can be used as hashmaps

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Agreed he should be using `Object` rather than `Array`, but JavaScript arrays **are** associative arrays. JavaScript arrays are everything JavaScript objects are, *plus* some special handling around numeric property keys and a `length` property. So his code using `Array` will work. But since it doesn't take advantage of any of the `Array`-ness, there's no reason to use `Array`.

Comment: If you want to post an answer your own question, that's perfectly fine, but post it *as an answer*. It makes it very hard to read the question when there's an answer intermixed with it. More: http://stackoverflow.com/faq Separately, see the live example in my answer for how you can initialize `events` much more clearly and efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fundamental approach is sound. A few notes:

1. You're not using `days` as an array, so I wouldn't make it an array. Instead:

   ```
   var days = {
       'SU': 0,
       'MO': 1,
       'TU': 2,
       'WE': 3,
       'TH': 4,
       'FR': 5,
       'SA': 6
   };
   ```

   Also, you don't *need* those quotes since none of those strings is a keyword, so:

   ```
   var days = {
       SU: 0,
       MO: 1,
       TU: 2,
       WE: 3,
       TH: 4,
       FR: 5,
       SA: 6
   };
   ```

   ...but you may choose to keep them as a style thing, or to defend against adding ones that are keywords later.
2. You don't have to use the bracketed notation to look up a property (`a['day']`) unless the string you're using for the property name is dynamic or the property name is a reserved word. `day` is neither, so you can use the simpler dotted notation (`a.day`).
3. There is no `elseif` in JavaScript; use `else if`.
4. You can simplify this:

   ```
   return (days[a['day']] < days[b['day']]) ? 1 : -1;
   ```

   to

   ```
   return days[a.day] - days[b.day];
   ```

   ..and you may be able to do something similar with your `time` values, but <s>I don't know what they are, so...</s> now that you've posted them, I do, and you can.
5. Strongly recommend *always* using braces, not just when you "need" them. (None of your three branches actually needs them, but you're only using them on two.)
6. You've compared `a['time']` to `a['time]` rather than `b['time']` when checking for equality.
7. You haven't ended your function (missing `}`)
8. Since you can just subtract your `time` values, you don't need your final equality check.

   So:

   ```
   events.sort(function(a, b)
   {
       if (a.day != b.day)
       {
           return days[a.day] - days[b.day];
       }
       else
       {
           return a.time - b.time;
       }
   });
   ```

   ...or you can condense it further:

   ```
   events.sort(function(a, b)
   {
       return (a.day != b.day
              ? days[a.day] - days[b.day]
              : a.time - b.time);
   });
   ```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ozazu3)

Comment: Thanks for your help, how does the - (minus) work? is b - a ascending? It works just doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: @Steven: If `a` is TU/8 and `b` is TU/6, `a.day == b.day` and then we return `b.time - a.time`, which is -2, which means that `b` should be before `a`. And similarly when we compare `days[a.day]` to `days[b.day]`. It should be sorting correctly if I'm understanding your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've put my solution at the top. How would I condense it?

Comment: @Steven: I seem to have had my `a`'s and `b`'s reversed. Edited, with example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Personally, I don't see it as a stylistic change - the list is now actually a list, instead of a bunch of `p` tags starting with `1)`, `2)`..., which is better markup.